# Strapi Start Install Issue on Mac

Tags: mongodb, strapi

Having an issue installing Strapi on my Mac. Not sure what is going on really. Tried running npm install strapi-hook-strapi-mongoose and ran into 404 Not Found: strapi-hook-strapi-mongoose@latest.

```
    USERs-MacBook-Pro:DIRECTORY USER$ strapi start
[2018-08-08T04:22:21.087Z] warn (hook:strapi-mongoose) `strapi-hook-strapi-mongoose` is missing in your dependencies. Please run `npm install strapi-hook-strapi-mongoose`
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: strapi.models.core_store.forge is not a function
    at Object.get (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/core/store.js:55:47)
    at module.exports (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/plugins/settings-manager/config/functions/bootstrap.js:17:26)
    at Promise (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:285:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at execBootstrap (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:273:11)
    at Promise.all.Object.values.map.x (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:312:44)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Strapi.bootstrap (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:312:35)
    at Strapi.start (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:107:18)
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:42355) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: strapi.models.core_store.forge is not a function
    at Object.get (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/core/store.js:55:47)
    at module.exports (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/plugins/users-permissions/config/functions/bootstrap.js:77:45)
    at Promise (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:285:13)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at execBootstrap (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:273:11)
    at Promise.all.Object.values.map.x (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:312:44)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Strapi.bootstrap (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:312:35)
    at Strapi.start (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:107:18)
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at fs.readdir (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/plugins/email/config/functions/bootstrap.js:53:40)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 6)
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at fs.readdir (/Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/plugins/upload/config/functions/bootstrap.js:55:40)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:42355) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 8)
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.197Z] info File changed: /Users/USER/Documents/GitHub/DIRECTORY/plugins/graphql/config/generated/schema.graphql
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.364Z] warn Bootstrap is taking unusually long to execute its callback 3500 miliseconds).
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.364Z] warn Perhaps you forgot to call it?
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.364Z] warn Bootstrap is taking unusually long to execute its callback 3500 miliseconds).
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.364Z] warn Perhaps you forgot to call it?
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.366Z] warn Bootstrap is taking unusually long to execute its callback 3500 miliseconds).
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.366Z] warn Perhaps you forgot to call it?
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.366Z] warn Bootstrap is taking unusually long to execute its callback 3500 miliseconds).
[2018-08-08T04:22:25.366Z] warn Perhaps you forgot to call it?
```

Comment: npm `strapi-hook-mongoose@alpha`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a common Mac bug, instead of using the 'strapi' command where I too got that error, I created my project using yarn and I was able to get past it.

```
yarn create strapi-app new-project-name
```

Answer (score 3):

Installation

> npm install strapi@alpha -g

Installation Guide

[For Strapi installation Guide, Click here](https://strapi.io/getting-started)